# Is there a vim snippet plugin that DOESN'T act like snipmate, textmate, etc.?

Tags: vim, code-snippets

I'm wondering if there is a snippet plugin that already exists that basically opens a file browser and allows one to select/search for a snippet name that will then insert a block of code. I'm a fan of the Textmate snippet feature personally; however, my environment has quite a few text-file-based snippets that I'd just like to read in. I'd like to be able to:

- Configure a directory
- Press a keystroke/enter a command to call up a window
- Type what I'm looking for or browse through folders
- Select a snippet
- Read it in

Thoughts, suggestions, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[mu-template](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate) has a `:MuEdit` command that permits to open&edit the snippets available (the name is the same than the one one can use with `:MuTemplate`). From within a snippet/template, `CTRL-W_f` (and may be `gf`, I don't remember) has been remapped to follow other included snippets/templates).

It may not be has ergonomic as what you have in mind as this feature is aimed at template-files maintenance, and not interactive expansion of snippets/templates. For this the snippets have a *hint* line that is more than enough in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd stop back by and respond with what I decided to do. I've installed [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) and made a few mappings to fit this need:

```
" Open Snippets
nnoremap <leader>so :CtrlP <directory to snippets><cr>
```

and

```
" Put Snippet
nnoremap <leader>sp :buffer #<cr>:read #<cr>:bdelete #<cr>
```

The first one just specifies the directory of the snippets. I can then search for the snippet I want, press enter and it opens. While on that snippet, I can use the second mapping to switch to my last buffer, read in the last active buffer (which should now be the snippet) then delete that buffer. I'm gonna give it a try for a couple of days and see how this works out.